# SAS - Allocating maximum memory for a hash table

Tags: sas

I have a table I'm trying to load into a hash object and I'm getting this message:

```
ERROR: Hash object added 1703920 items when memory failure occurred.
FATAL: Insufficient memory to execute DATA step program. Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.
ERROR: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of insufficient memory.
```

**My computer has sufficient spare RAM to load the table,** it just appears as though my SAS configuration is limiting how much RAM SAS will allocate to this task.

What settings do I need in order to force SAS to use the maximum amount of RAM?

Standalone SAS 9.3 running on a Windows XP box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MEMSIZE determines your maximum memory size, though there are a few other options that are useful to play around with (SORTSIZE should always change with MEMSIZE to be around 1/3 of MEMSIZE).

Note that if you run multiple sessions, MEMSIZE can be risky - if you have 4GB RAM and set MEMSIZE to 2GB, and have three SAS sessions open, you could crash the system or cause unintended results if you attempt to use all 2GB in all three sessions [ie, if you surpass your memory+page file total], and even if you don't surpass your page file, you might force Windows to use the page file for tasks that it shouldn't be used for.  I generally try to keep 2GB+ free around the MEMSIZE amount of physical RAM (so I have 16GB and use 12GB as my maximum MEMSIZE, and have two versions going at any one time - a BIGMEM config with 12GB and a normal 2GB config that I use for most of my work that won't benefit from huge MEMSIZE.

Comment: Looks like memsize is the culprit but it still doesn't behave as expected.  Monitoring the mem usage via either taskmgr or processexplorer I can see sas won't allocate more than 1Gb to the process even though I have memsize set to 2Gb and >2Gb available.

Answer (score 1):

To determine how much memory you have available for SAS use

```
data _null_;
    mem = getoption('xmrlmem');
    put mem=;
run
```

it gives a sense to the number of records that fit into the hash object, see [starting with hash objects](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/dot/hash-getting-started.pdf) by Secosky and Bloom.

If your hash table is too wide and this is the reason why you run out of memory, try breaking it into several narrower tables, so they will fit into the memory, and perform the hash join several times. It still may be faster than a regular join. You may also try changing **hashexp:** property of **DECLARE** statement in hash join definition.

There is a nice article about differnt joining techniques from [NESUG 2007](http://www.nesug.org/proceedings/nesug07/bb/bb16.pdf)

Without seeing the data, the code, or having at least a rough idea what are you resources and data, it is hard to help or suggest a workaround.